# Run <script> Sections Out of Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jekyll

I'm using HTML templates (Jekyll) and occasionally want to include scripts in the content of the template. For example, my page template looks like this

```
<body>
  {{ content }}
  <script src="some_library.js"></script>
  <script>
    // general setup stuff
  </script>
</body>
```

Where `{{ content }}` can sometimes include

```
<script>
  // page-specific code relying on some_library.js and general page setup stuff
</script>
```

I could just move the template scripts into the head of template, but I've read many times how important it is to put `<script>` at the end of the document. Can I reliably ensure that the page-specific code runs last even though it appears first?

I'm using jQuery, but if I include jQuery in the template, then it won't be available in the content script. I tried adding a `$(window).load` function around the content script, but I get `$ is not defined`.

Comment: You could simply use window.onload instead of $(window).load

Comment: That does the trick! Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly work with the window load event instead of $(window).load - no need for jQuery!

The simplest way:

```
window.onload= yourFunction;
```

[A cleaner way](http://ckon.wordpress.com/2008/07/25/stop-using-windowonload-in-javascript/) would be to rely on the attachEvent/addEventListener methods:

```
window.addEventListener ? 
window.addEventListener("load",yourFunction,false) : 
window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload",yourFunction);
```

(attachEvent is for older IE versions)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [.ready() function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

From the documentation:

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received.

Also from the docs:

```
$(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Comment: I saw that function but it's not clear to me that "all assets... have been completely received" implies that all other scripts have finished loading.